# React - Save the work before leaving the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using react, I'm trying to prevent the user from leaving a particular page displaying a message and saving his work.
I know that I could use Prompt to display a standard message with ok/cancel buttons, like this:

```
import { Prompt } from 'react-router'

<Prompt
  when={hasToBlockNavigation}
  message="Do you want to leave without saving?"
/>
```

but I'm looking for a way to display a custom component instead of the standard windows and to associate custom functions for the ok/cancel button. I found some other solution using the setRouteLeaveHook function, but it's not supported any more.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that the [`Prompt` component is only 70 lines of code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Prompt.js) - you could very feasibly write your own custom version if theirs doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can use "react-router-navigation-prompt" which is according to their document :-

> Promps user to confirm navigation. A replacement component for the react-router . Allows for more flexible dialogs.

```
npm i react-router-navigation-prompt
```

and then use your owm component like below - am using their example .

```
import NavigationPrompt from 'react-router-navigation-prompt';


import ConfirmNavigationModal from './your-own-code';

<NavigationPrompt when={this.state.shouldConfirmNavigation}>
  {({onConfirm, onCancel}) => (
    <ConfirmNavigationModal when={true} onCancel={onCancel} onConfirm={onConfirm}/>
  )}
</NavigationPrompt>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the NavigationPrompt component is only shown the page is changed because of a click on a link and not when I go back/forward

Comment: please let me if the next comment works- it works as 
// Confirm navigation if going to a path that does not start with current path:

Comment: when={(crntLocation, nextLocation) => !nextLocation.pathname.startsWith(crntLocation.pathname)}

Comment: no, it doesn't display the message (but I cannot go back now. The page is just reloaded)

Comment: can you post fiddle o sandbox so that i can help u more .

Comment: it's included in another project and it's quite difficult to extract in... anyway, I just added the control end added a Modal to rendere the pop up window, as the documentation said

Comment: i believe if the issue only in back and forward parts we can put listener on document to listen for the change on them nad use the value from it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170785/discussion-between-gepeppe-and-fadi-abo-msalam).

Comment: @gepeppe i can't right now but i can do it after 3 hours from now if that possible with you

Comment: thank you, but I can't... if tomorrow you will be available we can talk, otherwise do not worry, I do not want to bother you too much :)

Comment: no problem dude tomorrow it is but it will be much easier if you create small fiddle and included the code so i can modify it and give you the solution thanks